# Echoing out Calculated Distance Via SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I have gotten some code off of google to help me calculate distance between two objects in MYSQL however, and they also get properly sorted by that distance calculated...

Heres a Snippet of Code to help explain how I do that:

```
    $EQUASION = '( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$GPSLAT.') )
* cos( radians( field_Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( field_Longitude )
- radians('.$GPSLONG.') ) + sin( radians('.$GPSLAT.') )
* sin( radians( field_Latitude )) ) )
AS distance ';
```

My question is, how do I use and echo the Distance itself....

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){echo $row['distance']}
```

simply echoing the "row distance" does not seem to work, since its not acctually a field in the database, and its a calculated distance. how can I access this information so that I can properly display the information like "you are ##Km away from so-and-so object"

Comment: show your query please

Comment: the echo part should work. Doesn't seem to be anything wrong here. Is the query working correctly?

Comment: Anything in the `SELECT` clause of the query will be put in `$row`, it doesn't matter whether it's a field in the table or something calculated by the query.

Comment: I know its strange, the query returns just fine, and sorts just fine in my query editor.  but while echoing the row it always comes back blank, I'll have to check my files for any reason why it would be dropping the distance between the query and echo...  I had been looking up "AS" referances in mysql all night last night.   I will provide more details as I can collect them for you guys.. unfortunatly my Query Builder PHP file is over 50k so I'll be unable to post the entire file for you guys to view.

Answer (score 0):

While using the $row['distance'] AS distance variable durring calulations within the acctual loop itself there was a fundamental flaw causing a calculation to return false. thus I was never getting any returns.

I simply changed

```
if ($row['distance'] != 0) else {}
```

to

```
if ($row['distance'] > 0) else {}
```

and I started getting results back. in the case there were blank results or whatever it was triggering a variable wipe within the else statement after the if due to it always returning false.

My mistake simple typeo in a very very large file.